# If a single owner LLC is closed in Jan 2020, does the company owner still file a return in 2021?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, california, business

If someone has single owner LLC in California USA and if he/she closes the company in Jan 2020, do you still  have to file business tax return in 2021? Specially if company has elected financial year between Jan to December in the previous tax filing.

Comment: Yes, of course they do.

Comment: @RonBeyer, as long as they had income in Jan 2020.  If there was no income, then you don't need to file.

Comment: @gaefan That depends on State filling requirements, they may still have to file a "zero income" document.